# Skipping frames and retrieving movie file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video

I am trying to process a video in Matlab that I read in using `VideoReader`. I can process the the frames without a problem, but I only want to process every fifth frame. I tried using the step function but this doesn't work on my videoreader object. Right now I can call `readFrame` five times, but this obviously slows down the whole process (its a lot of video material). How can I efficiently skip five frames, process five frame, skip another five, ... using Matlab?

> Error message: 
>       Undefined function 'step' for input arguments of type 'VideoReader'.

However, calling the `help` function on `step` gets me this example:

```
WORKED=step(VR,DELTA)
Moves the frame counter by DELTA frames for video VR.  This is a 
generalization of NEXT.  Returns 0 on an unsuccessful step.  Note that 
not all plugins support stepping, especially with negative numbers.  In 
the following example, both IM1 and IM2 should be the same for most 
plugins.
  vr = videoReader(...myurl...);
  if (~next(vr)), error('couldn''t read first frame'); end
      im1 = getframe(vr);
  if (~step(vr,-1)), error('could not step back to frame 0'); end
      im2 = getframe(vr);
  if (any(im1 ~= im2)), 
      error('first frame and frame 0 are not the same'); 
  end
  vr = close(vr);
FNUM should be an integer.

After the videoReader constructor is called, NEXT, SEEK, or step should
be called at least once before GETFRAME is called.
```

Here, `step` is clearly called on a `VideoReader` object, is it not? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Matlab version?

Comment: `VR` is not equal to `vr`. And what are the `next` and `getframe` functions? How are you calling `step` and why is `step` creating it's own `VideoReader` object inside?

Comment: Did you write the `step` function or is that actually from [`vision.VideoFileReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-class.html)'s [`step`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader.step.html) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this issue too. Without using deprecated code, the only way to do what you are trying is to call [`readFrame`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html) five times for every output frame. This is slow and very inefficient. However, if you use the deprecated [`read`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html) method (and assuming your video is a file rather than a stream), you can specify a frame number as well. I don't know why The MathWorks have gone backwards on this. I suggest that you [file a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs) to ask about it and say why this functionality is important to you.

In the meantime, you can try out my [`frame2jpg`](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/08/) function that extracts particular frames from a video file. It tries to use the deprecated `read` method and falls back to `readFrame` if that fails. I've found the `read` method to be ten times faster in my own application with 1080p 60 fps MPEG-4 video. Feel free to modify the code to suit your your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer! I will try out the _read_ function and see if it speeds up the process.

Answer (score 0):

Don`t know if this is still of use but I´ve found a way to work around the issue.

As the readFrame reads the CURRENT frame, provided by the vid.CurrentTime property you can simply advance the property by the amount of frames you want to skip.

```
vid = VideoReader('myvid.mpeg')
vidFig = figure();
currAxes = axes;

n = 10;

while hasFrame(vid) 
vidFrame = readFrame(vid);
vid.CurrentTime = vid.CurrentTime + n/vid.FrameRate; 
image(vidFrame, 'Parent', currAxes);
currAxes.Visible = 'off';
end
```

Changing the value of n makes the video skip the amount of frames through every loop. I hope this helped.